# Python dataprep package seems to break pip-compile due to conflicting dependencies

Tags: python, pip, dataprep

I used the dataprep package in a jupyter notebook, installing via `!pip install dataprep` recently and it installed smoothly.

Now I'm tidying up some of that work and am using a venv, but `pip-compile` keeps crashing and I seem to have isolated dataprep as the cause. A minimal reproducible example below:

Given a `test_requirements.in` file which contains only a single line: `dataprep`

...Running `pip-compile test_requirements.in --verbose --output-file test_requirements.txt` yields the following error:

```
Could not find a version that matches executing<0.9.0,>=0.8.3,>=1.2.0 (from varname==0.8.3->dataprep==0.4.5->-r test_requirements.in (line 1))
Tried: 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.2.0, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.5.0, 0.5.2, 0.5.3, 0.5.3, 0.5.4, 0.5.4, 0.6.0, 0.6.0, 0.7.0, 0.7.0, 0.8.0, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.8.3, 0.9.0, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.2.0
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies:
  executing<0.9.0,>=0.8.3 (from varname==0.8.3->dataprep==0.4.5->-r test_requirements.in (line 1))
  executing>=1.2.0 (from stack-data==0.6.2->ipython==8.8.0->ipywidgets==7.7.2->dataprep==0.4.5->-r test_requirements.in (line 1))
```

I might be reading this wrong but it seems to be saying that one of `dataprep`'s dependencies requires a version of the `executing` package between 0.8.3 and 0.9, but another of `dataprep`'s dependencies requires a version of the `executing` package >=1.2. Is there any way to resolve this apparent contradiction with pip-compile?

Comment: Aside based on your first line: I think in your first line you meant `!pip install dataprep`.  Note though that you should be using `%pip install dataprep` equivalent in future installs. The magic command insures installs occur in the environment backing the kernel underlying the notebook, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). The exclamation point can lead to confusion/issues, see top of [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez).

Comment: you're right, that was a typo, just corrected. thanks.